# How can I create a security group that references all public IP addresses of my ec2 instances in AWS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elb, aws-security-group

We have an ELB Application load balancer that allows HTTP/HTTPS traffic from a customer managed prefix containing a list of our developer IP addresses. The load balancer forwards incoming requests to specific EC2 instances based on the hostname.

These instances need to be able to talk to each other via HTTP/HTTPS. For example, the [www.domain.com](http://www.domain.com) needs to talk to api.domain.com. I have put the load balancer and instances in the same security group and allowed all traffic between instances in the same security group (setting the security group id as the source for the rule).

I understand that by using hostnames that point to the load balancer, the request will travel out of the VPC and come back in - the security group rule only applies to the private IP addresses of the instances, right?

I have another customer managed prefix list containing the public IP addresses of each server, but that seems a little manual. Is there a better way to restrict HTTP/HTTPS access to the public IP addresses of all servers in our AWS account/specific security groups?

Is there a private hostname I could use for the load balancer, so that the request from the ec2 instance stays within the VPC?

Comment: Perhaps investigate the possibility of having two LBs: one internal and one internet-facing, with the same set of EC2 instances registered with each. Believe this is [viable with classic ELB](https://shlomoswidler.com/2009/07/ec2-instance-belonging-to-multiple-elbs/) but not sure about ALB. Or potentially a private API Gateway API [acting as a load balancer](https://dashbird.io/blog/can-api-gateway-act-load-balancer/). No hands-on with either, just throwing out things to investigate.

Comment: @jarmod it is viable with all forms of load balancers (ELB/ALB/NLB). I've used that setup with all of them in the past.

Comment: Perhaps you could include details about your subnets, route tables, NACL, and any other network-piping that might exist in this infrastructure?  Your load balancer has a listener?